# How do I query and XML column in SQL by attribute?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to query an XML column and return rows that match certain criteria. The XML column is called Configuration and a sample value looks like:

```
<feed>
    <schedule>
        <arrivalSla dayOfWeek="monday" time="02:00:00" />
    </schedule>
</feed>
```

I want to return all rows that have a time of "04:00:00".

I have found out how to query a simple XML column that does not have attributes such as time. I need to query on the attribute however.

Comment: The only difference is that you must append at character. Something like: select @x.value('feed[1]/schedule[1]/arrivalSla[1]/@time', 'time')

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, Configuration XML)

INSERT INTO @Sample (ID, Configuration)
VALUES (1, '<feed>
    <schedule>
        <arrivalSla dayOfWeek="Monday" time="02:00:00" />
    </schedule>
</feed>'), (2, '<feed>
    <schedule>
        <arrivalSla dayOfWeek="Tuesday" time="04:00:00" />
    </schedule>
</feed>'), (3, '<feed>
    <schedule>
        <arrivalSla dayOfWeek="Wednesday" time="05:00:00" />
    </schedule>
</feed>')

SELECT
    ID,
    XmlDayOfWeek = s.Configuration.value('(/feed/schedule/arrivalSla/@dayOfWeek)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @Sample s
WHERE
    s.Configuration.value('(/feed/schedule/arrivalSla/@time)[1]', 'varchar(20)') = '04:00:00'
```

This will produce a result of:

```
ID    XmlDayOfWeek
------------------
2     Tuesday
```